Launcher item with my email and options "New Window" or "Mount" cannot be removed
I just upgraded to 24.04 -- the new launcher has an odd icon below a line:

It's above the trash icon.  When I right click it, I get two options, "New Window" and "Mount".  If I select either item, I get an error saying "Failed to Mount" and "Invalid credentials".  If I run my cursor over the icon it shows my email name.  I can't get rid of this thing, nor can I find a location for what it thinks it is (apparently a new drive?).
I see a mountain of .desktop files in /usr/share/applications, but which file, if any, is the offending file?  Presumably I just delete that file.  On the other hand, why is the icon where the trash icon is -- that is, part of the GUI. Maybe the file is somewhere else.  How do I find it?

Easy!  Settings-->Dock-->Configure Dock Behavior-->
Remove the check next to "Include Unmounted Volumes".
